# Is it possible to change the primitive value of a Boolean object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I know you should never use Boolean objects in JS in place of Boolean primitives. This is just curiosity.

```
var foo = new Boolean();
```

Primitive value of foo is now `false`. How can I change it to `true`?

Comment: `foo = true;`<padding>

Comment: No; it's immutable.

Comment: you can do it like this : foo = new Boolean(true)

Comment: > Do not create Boolean objects. It slows down execution speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you can't. `Boolean`, `String`, `Number` - none of them have methods to change their value because they are **immutable**. `Date` does have setter methods, but under the hood the object is probably being discarded and replaced with a new one with the newly set property.

```
var date = new Date();  // Tue Feb 21 2017 11:28:21 GMT-0600 (CST)
date.setFullYear(2016); // Sun Feb 21 2016 11:28:21 GMT-0600 (CST)
```

Answer (score 1):

The boolean object is just a container of a bool value and it can't be changed.

**Moreover, is not advised to use it because it slow down the execution speed and new keyword complicate the code as described in the documentation at:**

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp